# Как в xaml сложить/умножить переменные?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Нужно переменную разделить на два. Пример:

```
TextBlock.FontSize="{Binding ElementName=buttonControl1, Path=Height/2}"
```

Upd:
Так не получается:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <!--Конвертер-->
        <local:FontSizeConverter x:Key="fontSizeConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="buttonControl1" Content="Push!" Template = "{StaticResource buttonTemplate}" Height="100" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=buttonControl1, Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource fontSizeConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

_

```
public class FontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value / 2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value * 2;
    }
}
```

Ругается в XAML на биндинд FontSize'a "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Базово для этого и придуманы конвертеры. Также куча самопальных биндингов с возможностью арифметики, но это уже тем кто не боится просадок в производительности (неизвестно какой)

Comment: Ругается в дизайнере или при сборке или в рантайме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенесите `Path` на первую позицию.

```
FontSize="{Binding Path=Height, ElementName=buttonControl1, Converter={StaticResource fontSizeConverter}}"
```

если после этого что то пойдет не так попробуйте пересобрать проект.